# How do you change an enum value to a more readable string that is bound to a UltraGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have an Infragistics UltraGrid with a bound list of various datatypes. One of these is an enum with non-human readable values. I would like to change the display to something more readable.

In the code base people have been hiding the enum column and adding a string column with the desired values. This doesn't seem right to me. Is there a way of changing the displayed enum values that would be more readable?

Example. Not Readable:
SomeUnreadableEnumValue
Some_Unreadable_Enum_Value

Readable:
Some Readable Text

**Update:** 
I am aware of using Description attributes

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("Description for Foo")]
    Foo,
    [Description("Description for Bar")]
    Bar
}
```

as mentioned here [See Thomas Levesque answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415140/can-my-enums-have-friendly-names?lq=1). I just can't figure out how to bind this description attribute to an UltraGrid that is already bound to an enum.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531739/linking-enum-value-with-localized-string-resource

Comment: @Marton I have already tried the Description attribute approach. This is actually the approach I want to take. The problem is how to get the grid to display this value when it is already bound to an enum.

Comment: Not sure if you already looked at this link,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773303/splitting-camelcase

Answer (score 1):

I just create a property that returns the description and bind to it

```
public override string UserTextOp
{
    get
    {
        Type enumType = typeof(enumTextCond);
        string name = Enum.GetName(enumType, cond1SelectedKeyEnum);
        if (name != null)
        {
            FieldInfo field = enumType.GetField(name);
            if (field != null)
            {
                DescriptionAttribute attr =
                        Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
                            typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
                if (attr != null)
                    name = attr.Description;
            }
            return name;
        }
        return string.Empty;

    }
}
```