# Friendly-Format Enum for use in ComboBoxes, CheckedListBoxes, etc

Tags: c#, listview, combobox, enums, checkedlistbox

#### Requirement

I want to select values from an `enum` in C# using a `ComboBox` or select bitmasks (for `enum`s with the `Flags` attribute) with a `CheckedListBox`. I want a way to add the values to the controls as selectable items, and cleanly tell which the user has selected.

#### Objective 1: User-friendly

I also want the selection to be clear and pretty to the user. Currently I can already add `Enum` values to a `ComboBox` or a `CheckedListBox`, but `Enum.ToString()` will return the identifier name. Pascal Case is good enough for me, but not for my users.

#### Objective 2: Easy to code

I want this to be easy to code. I mean **easy**. I want this to be a mere afterthought to defining and/or using **any** `enum` value.

#### My Solution

Now I looked around and saw several nice solutions. Some of them are better in their own ways, like [if you really need to put in your own custom descriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524647/string-from-byte-enum), or to take it one step further, [support multiple languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796607/how-do-i-have-an-enum-bound-combobox-with-custom-string-formatting-for-enum-valu). You can do [fake enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630803/associating-enums-with-strings-in-c-sharp) too. But I kept looking, and none of them had quite the combination of elegance and simplicity--for my purposes--as what I wrote. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basis of my solution is a `struct` that can wrap `Enum` values and override `ToString()`.

Enter the `EnumWrapper`:

```
public struct EnumWrapper
{
    private readonly Enum e;
    public EnumWrapper(Enum e) {
        this.e = e;
    }
    public static implicit operator Enum(EnumWrapper wrapper) {
        return wrapper.e;
    }
    public static explicit operator EnumWrapper(Enum e) {
        return new EnumWrapper(e);
    }
    public override string ToString() {
        return e.ToStringFriendly();
    }
}
```

The method `ToStringFriendly()` is defined as an extension method on `Enum`:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public static class _Extensions
{
    public static string ToStringFriendly(this Enum e)
    {
        string s = e.ToString();

        // enforce a charset: letters, numbers, and underscores
        s = Regex.Replace(s, "[^A-Za-z0-9_]", ""); 

        // separate numbers from letters
        s = Regex.Replace(s, "([a-zA-Z])([0-9])", "$1 $2"); 

        // separate letters from numbers
        s = Regex.Replace(s, "([0-9])([a-zA-Z])", "$1 $2"); 

        // space lowercases before uppercase (word boundary)
        s = Regex.Replace(s, "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2"); 

        // see that the nice pretty capitalized words are spaced left
        s = Regex.Replace(s, "(?!^)([^ _])([A-Z][a-z]+)", "$1 $2"); 

        // replace double underscores with colon-space delimiter
        s = Regex.Replace(s, "__", ": "); 

        // finally replace single underscores with hyphens
        s = Regex.Replace(s, "_", "-"); 

        return s;
    }
}
```

Now, to add any `Enum` value to a ComboBox, for example,

```
comboBox.Items.Add((EnumWrapper)MyEnum.SomeValue);
```

And to get it back out (after null-testing, of course):

```
MyEnum myValue = (MyEnum)(Enum)(EnumWrapper)comboBox.SelectedItem;
```

And that's it. Now what are the pros and cons of this approach?

#### The Pros:

- You can pass the enum values (almost) directly in and out of your controls. Just cast back and forth to/from `EnumWrapper`.
- This works nicely for all Pascal-cased `Enum` values with a few special cases. One example might be a value called `MyValue__DescriptionOf123_ENUMValue` which would come out of `ToStringFriendly()` as *"My Value: Description of 123-ENUM Value"*.
- The mechanics (a `struct` and an extension method) can be written once and tucked out of the way. There is no additional coding in each `Enum`. This means it works nicely as above **for enums you didn't write**, assuming Pascal case, which in .NET is a good assumption. *Note: This is why I'd say [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796607/how-do-i-have-an-enum-bound-combobox-with-custom-string-formatting-for-enum-valu), however elegant, is not a better solution than mine, as it requires that you can add a `TypeConverter` attribute to each `Enum`.*

#### The Cons:

- This doesn't support **custom descriptions** or **multiple languages**. For example a value like `Encoding.EBCDIC` will always come through as "EBCDIC" and does not allow you to manually type "Extended Binary Coded Decimal Interchange Code", much less other languages.

#### Future Work

One could add custom descriptions and multi-language support by changing `ToStringFriendly()` to do a language-lookup for that value before de-Pascal-casing.

For more Regex fun, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621464/camelcase-conversion-to-friendly-name-i-e-enum-constants-problems).

Comment: If you are trying to wrap an enum it is very strange that you are using an extension method for the ToFriendlyString that logic should be defined in your wrapper to keep it a wrapper.

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey: Not really. This way you can call `ToStringFriendly()` on any `Enum` at any time yourself, without first turning it into an `EnumWrapper`. I only created `EnumWrapper` to make `ToStringFriendly()` the default that combo boxes and such use.