# "Display" or "Description" attribute for enum values allowing multiple usage

Tags: c#, enums, attributes

I’d like to use an attribute for parsing strings to enum values (something like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787506/get-enum-from-enum-attribute)), but I’d like to use *multiple* strings for each enum value, e.g.:

```
enum Foo
{
    [SomeAttribute("A BAR")]
    [SomeAttribute("The BAR")]
    Bar,
    [SomeAttribute("A BUZZ")]
    [SomeAttribute("The BUZZ")]
    Buzz
}
```

That means that I cannot use `Description` nor `DisplayName` because they have `AllowMultiple=false`.

I know that it is simple to create my own attribute, but:

Does the .NET framework already contain a suitable attribute that I can use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't. Go with creating your own attribute.