# Regular DateTime question

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, windows-services

I'm writing a service but I want to have config settings to make sure that the service does not run within a certain time window on one day of the week. eg Mondays between 17:00 and 19:00.

Is it possible to create a datetime that represents any monday so I can have one App config key for DontProcessStartTime and one for DontProcessEndTime with a values like "Monday 17:00" and "Monday 19:00"?

Otherwise I assume I'll have to have separate keys for the day and time for start and end of the time window.

Any thoughts?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a utility that will parse your weekday text into a System.DayOfWeek enumeration, [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424971/parse-string-to-enum-type). You can then use the Enum in a comparison against the `DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek`

Comment: There is Enum.TryParse generic method in .NET 4.0

Comment: @Andrew Bezzub - Good to know, great comment!

Comment: In case you are not using .NET 4.0 the DateTime struct also has a TryParse method.

Comment: @Fischer - Would DateTime.TryParse extract anything useful out of "Monday 17:00"?

Comment: I am not sure of that, I expect it is necessary to do some preprocessing. It was just as an alternative to the .NET 4.0 Enum.Parse method.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the day of the week and start hour and endhour in your config file, and then use a function similar to the following:

```
public bool ShouldRun(DateTime dateToCheck)
{
     //These should be read from your config file:
     var day = DayOfWeek.Monday;
     var start = 17;
     var end = 19;

     return !dateToCheck.DayOfWeek == day &&
            !(dateToCheck.Hour >= start && dateToCheck.Hour < end);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DayOfTheWeek` property of the `DateTime`.
And to check proper time you can use `DateTime.Today` (returns date-time set to today with time set to 00:00:00) and add to it necessary amount of hours and minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This is very rough code, but illustrates that you can check a DateTime object containing the current time as you wish to do:

```
protected bool IsOkToRunNow()
{
    bool result = false;

    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

    if (currentTime.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday && (currentTime.Hour <= 17 || currentTime.Hour >= 19))
    {
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime` object cannot handle a value that means all mondays.  It would have to be a specific Monday.  There is a `DayOfWeek` enumeration.  Another object that may help you is a `TimeSpan` object.  You could use the `DayOfWeek` combined with `TimeSpan` to tell you when to start, then use another `TimeSpan` to tell you how long